# For Loops to copy and edit DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I want to create 24 dataframes in a Loop, where the first dataframe is created by:

```
df_hour_0 = df_dummies.copy()
df_hour_0['Price_24_1'] = df_hour_0['Price_REG1']
df_hour_0['Price_24_2'] = df_hour_0['Price_REG2']
df_hour_0['Price_24_3'] = df_hour_0['Price_REG3']
df_hour_0['Price_24_4'] = df_hour_0['Price_REG4']

df_hour_0[['Price_24_1', 'Price_24_2', 'Price_24_3', 'Price_24_4'
           ]] = df_hour_0[['Price_24_1', 'Price_24_2', 'Price_24_3', 'Price_24_4']].shift(1)
```

First, I tried this approach, which doesn't work. (Maybe another version of this approach can work?).

```
for i in range(24):
    df_hour_i = df_dummies.copy()
    df_hour_i['Price_24_1'] = df_hour_i['Price_REG1']
    df_hour_i['Price_24_2'] = df_hour_i['Price_REG2']
    df_hour_i['Price_24_3'] = df_hour_i['Price_REG3']
    df_hour_i['Price_24_4'] = df_hour_i['Price_REG4']
    df_hour_i[['Price_24_1', 'Price_24_2', 'Price_24_3', 'Price_24_4']] = df_hour_0[['Price_24_1', 'Price_24_2', 'Price_24_3', 'Price_24_4']].shift(i+1)
```

Now I have read that people, in general, recommend using a dictionary so I have tried this:

```
d = {}
for x in range(23):
    d[x] = pd.DataFrame()
```

which gives me 24 empty DF in one dictionary, but now I struggle with how to fill them.

Comment: `dfs = [df_hour_0.shift(i) for i in range(24)]`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That's a big step forward, this makes all columns shifts though, while I only want the 'Price_24_1', 'Price_24_2', 'Price_24_3', 'Price_24_4' to shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a list of DataFrames like this:

```
cols =  ['Price_24_1', 'Price_24_2', 'Price_24_3', 'Price_24_4']
dfs = []

for i in range(24):
    df = df_hour_0.copy()
    df[cols] = df[cols].shift(i)
    dfs.append(df)
```

Shift by `i` will be at index `i`.

Comment: That works like a charm, thank you! Now I will try to understand each step.

Comment: @SimonRydstedt the loop makes a copy of `df_hour_0`, then shifts the target columns in the copy by the loop variable `i`, and  finally appends the copy to the list `dfs`.

Comment: I am trying to separate each of the objects in the list now, I make it work until : ```for i in range(24):
    dfs[i] = dfs[i][dfs[i]['hour_0'] == 1]``` but I would like the ```'hour_0'``` to change too, I tried ```'hour_i'``` but that don't work.

Comment: @SimonRydstedt `f'hour_{i}'`.